# Use Case Diagram to Class Diagram Conversion Tool

Tags: uml

Is there any software tool that I can convert
a use case diagram to a class diagram?

Thanks,

Amanda

Comment: I hope you had a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2431025/use-case-to-class-diagram-how-do-i

Comment: And to answer your question, there is no single way to convert any use case to class diagram. From my perspective, it is more of an art and will vary significantly on how extensible the Architect wants the design to be. And frankly, the basics are not that difficult to pick up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No software will do such thing.

> Use case diagram provides very high level of your system dynamic behavior.
>
> Class diagram provides static view of a single module in your system.

These 2 entities have no tight coupling; use case diagram can have a zillion corresponding valid class diagrams and vice versa.

Comment: I knew we could convert a entity-relationship diagram to a class diagram using software and I was just checking if this option was now plausible.  Thanks though.

Comment: That's because ERD and class diagram are essentially 2 ways for describing more or less similar things. And even in this case, I'm not sure how good automatic conversion would be.